Why isn't my font being applied in Next.js?
I am trying to apply a font to my website, but it's not working.
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

* {
  background-color: black;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: 'cool';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@font-face {
      font-family: '';
  src: url('/portfolio/public/T16436-OT/T16436-OT/AO-Katana-Oblique.otf');
}

I made sure that the file path/URL  for the font was correct but still couldn't get it to work. This is the link of the font that I am trying to use if it matters -> https://www.youworkforthem.com/font/T16436/ao-katana

see this https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts
